# Why can you not edit records with Web API 2? Is it not possible?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

No one knows how to edit records! Does no one perform this action? The POST, GET and DELETE all work but PUT, regardless of what you do, does not work. Does no one edit records using an Web API2 from ASP.NET?

I have used both Hurl.it and POSTMAN and neither one of them can perform an edit using PUT. It just produces a 400 error - there is no information about the error because there is nothing wrong with the request!

Is there someone in the world who has managed to edit records with this? When the bounty becomes available I will give as much as I can - please someone inform us how this action can be performed.

How has anyone not even noticed that this API does not work fully? I do nto know where else to ask! No one on the ASP.NET forums knows how to do it either.

HURL.IT

1. yoururl/api/objects/id
2. parameter fieldname: value (all)
3. Click "Launch request"
4. The field gets edited

In Web API 2 - 400 error... no other information (because there is nothing wrong with request)

POSTMAN - same as above (more or less)

Code inside controller:

```
// PUT: api/Table1s/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
    public IHttpActionResult PutTable1(int id, Table1 table1)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        if (id != table1.TestID)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        db.Entry(table1).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!Table1Exists(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }
```

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you have tried so far. That way people can use it to reproduce the problem and give much better answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can I not perform a simple PUT edit on Web API 2 using hurl.it or POSTMAN?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36800616/why-can-i-not-perform-a-simple-put-edit-on-web-api-2-using-hurl-it-or-postman)

Comment: HTTP PUT - I said that in the question. It is a simple HTTP request. You use PUT, the URL and the id and then put parameters. It does not work in web api2. It is an API so I was under the assumption that it could perform actions to edit records - it gives a 400 error and there is seemingly no information as to why it does not work.

Comment: It is automatically created in a Web API 2 project. The method is there because it is scaffolded. I have made no modifications to the code so it is just the Web API 2 with default scaffolding.

Comment: The fact that you get **400 Bad Request** and not **405 Method Not Allowed** should at least make it plausible that the **Put**  can be used. I use it all the time when creating RESTful api. You need to provide more information on how your setup is and how you are making the request if you want others to help you.

Comment: Please just say what you did then? How did you perform the action? How did you edit a record? Are you using Web API 2?

Comment: Show code you've tried. you explain what you did but unless you show what you did other can't fix any mistakes or omissions that were made

Comment: What I did applies to my situations which may not necessarily apply to your situation. that is why you need to show what you have to any corrections/advice can be given. Are you doing your routes by convention or are you using attribute routing. all of this is information needed to better help you. I'm just trying to get you to better explain your problem.

Comment: I have modified question. All that has been done is default - it out of the box. POST, GET, DELETE all work fine. PUT produces 400 error for no reason. No authentication - it is just a test. VS2015.

Comment: Show the controller and action that is not working. show where you configure your routes. You could even `EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing` while debugging to get a more detailed error message. Are you using attribute routing or routing by convention

Comment: Now that you've shown some code we can see exactly why you keep getting back **400 Bad Request**. Your action returns 400 if the model state is not valid or if the ids don't match. Which would indicate that you are not constructing your requests properly.  In future I would advise that you lead with the code that is not working before going off on a tangent (IMHO)

Comment: I have managed to get it to work... 2 days of wasted time because of lack of information about how to perform a proper request.For some reason it was telling me about the fact that I needed all other fields. What it failed to indicate was that: as well as needing to put the field in the request URL... I needed to put it in the body as well. 2 days of wasted time... I will not delete my question because you have answered it. By the way - all of the configurations that you have done there are part of the default. Thank you anyway for your time and effort.

Comment: Not a problem. Glad to help and happy you found a solution to your problem. If my answer was of any use to you don't forget to up-vote. thanks

Answer (score 1):

If your are using [Attribute Routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#add-routes), your controller could look something like this...

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Table1s")]
public class Table1Controller : ApiController {

    // PUT: api/Table1s/5
    [HttpPut]
    [Route("{id:int}")]
    [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
    public IHttpActionResult PutTable1(int id, [FromBody]Table1 table1) {...}

}
```

A request to that action might look like ...

```
PUT http://localhost:5076/api/Table1s/5 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:5076
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 55

{
  "fieldname1":"value1",
  "fieldname2":"value2"
}
```

Make sure that you configured attribute routing along with your default configuration

```
//....
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes()

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
);
//....
```